# Window timeout alert

Tags: javascript, timeout

How can I improve this window timeout alert code? I need to add it to some third-party master page and don't want to add a separate file for it.

It must be JS only and IE-8 supported.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03rLey2L/6/)

```
(function () {
//    timedRefresh(10); //3600000
    delayedAlert();

    var timeoutID;

    function delayedAlert() {
        clearAlert();
      timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 10000);
    }

    function slowAlert() {
      alert("You may have been logged out due to inactivity. Click OK to refresh the page.");
    }

    function clearAlert() {
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    }
})();
```

Comment: is this for a server side session timeout?

Comment: @Malachi yes, we have TMG server for that

Comment: I don't think you are hosting a website on TMG, are you?  when you say Master page I assume you are talking about ASP (Active Server Pages) that make use of Microsoft's .NET framework.  why aren't you handling session timeout?

Comment: @Malachi following what manager says... we are using SharePoint master page, where i am going to add this code, its a  quick fix, we may come back to it later on, but atm it serves the purpose :)

Comment: again, I ask, why aren't you using the session timeout. you are making a random timeout value that doesn't correlate to anything except for a magic number.

Comment: @Malachi are you proposing changes to web.configs, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473(VS.90).aspx, or do you want me to add code behind sessiontimeout like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239798/Session-Timeout-Warning-and-Redirect  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27385/discussion-between-malachi-and-mathematics).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points to make about this:

> ```
> (function () {
> //    timedRefresh(10); //3600000
>     delayedAlert();
>
>     var timeoutID;
>
>     function delayedAlert() {
>         clearAlert();
>       timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 10000);
>     }
>
>     function slowAlert() {
>       alert("You may have been logged out due to inactivity. Click OK to refresh the page.");
>     }
>
>     function clearAlert() {
>       window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
>     }
> })();
> ```

- `slowAlert`/`delayedAlert` can be improved by moving `slowAlert` into `delayedAlert` as follows:

```
function delayedAlert() {
    clearAlert();
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function(){
        alert("You may have been logged out due to inactivity. Click OK to refresh the page.");
    }, 10000);
}
```

- I can't see why the `clearTimeout` call deserves its own function, when it only gets called from `delayedAlert`; You could just put it in `delayedAlert`:

```
function delayedAlert() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function(){
        alert("You may have been logged out due to inactivity. Click OK to refresh the page.");
    }, 10000);
}
```

- You can make `delayedAlert` an anonymous function, so that it cannot be called other than inside that block by changing `function delayedAlert()` into `var delayedAlert = function()`
- You call `delayedAlert` before `timeoutID` is defined:

> ```
> delayedAlert();
>
> var timeoutID;
> ```

If you're going to use globals (*which are recommended against*), declare them first, at the top.

```
(function(){
    var timeoutID;
    // functions and whatnot
    delayedAlert();
```

---

All resulting in:

```
(function(){
    var timeoutID;
    var delayedAlert = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function(){
            alert("You may have been logged out due to inactivity. Click OK to refresh the page.");
        }, 10000);
    }
    delayedAlert();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are writing this for an ASPX page, so I am suggesting that you use the Server's session timeout instead of using a magic number for the timeout.

in this function:

> ```
> function delayedAlert() {
>     clearAlert();
>   timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 10000);
> }
> ```

you could write it like this

```
function delayedAlert() {
    var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
    clearAlert();
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, sessionTimeout);
}
```

this way you won't timeout too early or timeout too late, you will always timeout almost exactly as the session times out.

---

*Extra Information was gathered from a [discussion posted in a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27385/discussion-between-malachi-and-mathematics) along with the comments to the OP*